# Filling gaps within a multipolygon using Python

Tags: python, geometry, shapely, fill, multi-polygon

I would like to know how can I fill the gaps within a multipolygon. The convex hull isn't the proper solution, since they change the geometry completely. I have attached a sample figure of such a multipolygon (A) and the result of convex hull (B).

[image]

I am also specifying the input multipolygon that is drawn in the sample image. Please consider the below as the input multipolygon.

```
from shapely.wkt import loads
bound = loads('MULTIPOLYGON(((7515704.00416809 7120667.47744681,7516615.43389189 7120908.05804233,7517359.10228519 7119917.87996673,7516492.76044512 7119713.74812422,7516153.62704039 7119393.96768349,7515166.003333894 7120350.499439177,7515714.11412775 7119266.57283074,7515509.90373781 7119270.31795147,7515013.44156286 7120432.23751209,7515398.51370746 7120586.840317,7515440.21487358 7120823.97722738,7515674.32840975 7120677.40035231,7515704.00416809 7120667.47744681),(7515834.55479406 7119853.71762937,7515945.36454446 7120192.66561018,7516026.84254783 7119723.35288365,7515834.55479406 7119853.71762937),(7515375.019416 7120205.70217427,7515371.76020038 7120453.39495243,7515645.52595753 7120466.43136732,7515554.27060568 7120202.44295865,7515375.019416 7120205.70217427)))')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not shorter, but using `geoms` method for a multi-geometry is more comprehensible.

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, MultiPolygon    
from shapely.wkt import loads

multi_polygon = loads('MULTIPOLYGON(((7515704.00416809 7120667.47744681,7516615.43389189 7120908.05804233,7517359.10228519 7119917.87996673,7516492.76044512 7119713.74812422,7516153.62704039 7119393.96768349,7515166.003333894 7120350.499439177,7515714.11412775 7119266.57283074,7515509.90373781 7119270.31795147,7515013.44156286 7120432.23751209,7515398.51370746 7120586.840317,7515440.21487358 7120823.97722738,7515674.32840975 7120677.40035231,7515704.00416809 7120667.47744681),(7515834.55479406 7119853.71762937,7515945.36454446 7120192.66561018,7516026.84254783 7119723.35288365,7515834.55479406 7119853.71762937),(7515375.019416 7120205.70217427,7515371.76020038 7120453.39495243,7515645.52595753 7120466.43136732,7515554.27060568 7120202.44295865,7515375.019416 7120205.70217427)))')

no_holes = MultiPolygon(Polygon(geom.exterior) for geom in multi_polygon.geoms)
```

Answer (score 5):

I got the answer myself.

```
no_holes = MultiPolygon(Polygon(p.exterior) for p in bound)
```

The above code does the job for me.